# Using symbols as data

Tags: sql, database, activerecord

I am going to have a column in my table that will be binary (the two states are 'private' and 'public'. Is there a way to use symbols for this purpose (:public and :private)? I would prefer this than using binary (ones and zeroes) and I know symbols are less memory-intensive than strings.

By the way I'm doing this in a Rails app with active record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use symbols in the database.

If you're worried about memory usage of strings over symbols, you can do better than both: Just use a boolean column, `private`, and have a `public?` accessor which returns `!private?`